# Homogeneous First Order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this problem today in Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes by George F. Simons, and I almost do not know how to start off. I need help. It says,

Show that the substitution
 z = ax + by + c 
changes 
y′ = f (ax + by + c)
into an equation with separable variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substitute $z=ax+by+c \to z'=by'+a$

$$y′ = f (ax + by + c)$$
$$y' =f(z)$$
For $b \ne 0$ 
$$\frac {z'-a}{b}=f(z)$$
$${z'}=bf(z)+a$$
this form of the equation is separable
$$\int\frac {dz}{bf(z)+a}=\int dx=x+K$$

---

Edit for $b=0$
It's already separable..
$$y′ = f (ax  + c)$$
$$\int dy =\int  f (ax  + c)dx $$
$$y =\int  f (ax  + c)dx $$

Comment: Hmm. I actually thought of this but I was skeptical about it because it would fail if b=0. Is it right for me to conclude that b cannot be 0 because if it were then, y would disappear from the function and the whole formulation would crumble?

Comment: even if $b=0$ its still separable @AgboolaOlumuyiwaDamilare